# operator priority problem about Reverse Polish Notation Calculator

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for atof() */
#define MAXOP 100 /* max size of operand or operator */
#define NUMBER '0' /* signal that a number was found */
int getop(char []);
void push(double);
double pop(void);
/* reverse Polish calculator */
main()
{
    int type;
    double op2;
    char s[MAXOP];
    while ((type = getop(s)) != EOF) {
        switch (type) {
            case NUMBER:
            push(atof(s));
            break;
            case '+':
            push(pop() + pop());
            break;
            case '*':
            push(pop() * pop());
            break;
            case '-':
            op2 = pop();
            push(pop() - op2);
            break; 
            case '/':
            op2 = pop();
            if (op2 != 0.0)
                push(pop() / op2);
            else
                printf("error: zero divisor\n");
            break;
            case '\n':
            printf("\t%.8g\n", pop());
            break;
            default:
            printf("error: unknown command %s\n", s);
            break;
        }
    }
}

#define MAXVAL 100

int sp = 0;
double val[MAXVAL];

void push(double f)
{
    if(sp < MAXVAL)
        val[sp++]=f;
    else
        printf("error:stack full, cant push %g\n",f);
}

double pop(void)
{
    if(sp>0)
        return val[--sp];
    else
    {
        printf("error: stack empty\n");
        return 0.0;
    }
}

#include<ctype.h>

int getch(void);
void ungetch(int);

int getop(char *s)
{
    char c;

    while ((*s = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
        ;
    *(s + 1) = '\0';
    if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.')
        return c;
    if (isdigit(c))
    {
        while (isdigit(*s++ = c = getch()))
            ;
    }
    if (c == '.')
    {
        while (isdigit(*s++ = c = getch()))
            ;
    }
    *s = '\0';
    if (c != EOF)
        ungetch(c);
    return number;
}

char buf[30];
char *Bufp = buf;

int getch(void)
{
    return (Bufp > buf) ? *(--Bufp) : getchar();
}

void ungetch(int c)
{
    if (c != EOF)
        *Bufp++ = c;
    else
        printf("no space\n”);
}
```

the result as follows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2I0Z.png)

when i changed this section.

```
int getch(void);
void ungetch(int);

int getop(char *s)
{
    char c;

    while ((*s = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
        ;
    *(s + 1) = '\0';
    if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.')
        return c;
    if (isdigit(c))
    {
        while (isdigit(*++s = c = getch()))
            ;
    }
    if (c == '.')
    {
        while (isdigit(*++s = c = getch()))
            ;
    }
    *s = '\0';
    if (c != EOF)
        ungetch(c);
    return number;
}
```

the result was correct.
the result was as follow[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmHSs.png)

**So i know there must be difference between**

```
while (isdigit(*++s = c = getch()))
```

and

```
while (isdigit(* s++ = c = getch()))
```

this problem must be relative to the operator priority. But I still didn't understand the reason why it happened. would you like to help me? or could you tell me the similar question? because i have been in search of it for a long time.

**——————————————————————The above problem was already solved.The new question was as follows.**

at first,Thank you guys for helping me and giving me new direction about above problem.
But i still had question.
For

```
while (isdigit(*++s = c = getch()))
```

i use better understandable way to achieve the same effect

```
        while (c = getch())
        {
            ++s;
            if (isdigit(*s = c))
                ;
            else
                break;
        }
```

The same way for

```
while (isdigit(* s++ = c = getch()))
```

the better understandable codes

```
while (c = getch())
        {
            if (isdigit(*s = c))
            {
                s++;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
```

the thing i didn't understand is `* s++ = c` which is equal to `* (s++) = c`. why isn't the statement same as the following codes?

```
s++;
*s = c;
```

the operator`++`'s precedence is higher than `*` and`=`, right?

Comment: If you don't understand what exactly  `while (isdigit(* s++ = c = getch()))` does, find another, better understandable way to achieve the same (convert it into a series of statements that each do exactly one thing).

Comment: see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @Ronald got it. but i still had problem i couldn't understand.Could you see my new problem?

Comment: @stark but i still had a new question? could you know why it happened?

Comment: Because `';'` has even higher precedence but is not listed on the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh, i got it. **A operator which has higher precedence doesn't necessarily mean it happens first.** especially, for post increment, it doesn't happen **until variable has effective value(or the value has been used)**.

So, first we get a character for  `getch()`,and then assign it to `c` variable. next, for`* s++ = c`, although it is equal to `* (s++) = c`, increment doesn't happen until `s` pointer variable have its effective value. execute the statement `*s = c`.
finally, if `*s` is a digit, do the  `s++`.